# Vertical images being rotated horizontally when adding and saving to NSAttributedString in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for days. When resizing an image that's in a NSAttributedString using NSTextAttachment the vertical images are saved horizontally. The resizing extension is working fine, but when the image is added to the NSAttributedString, it gets flipped horizontally for some reason. I am still new to Xcode. Any help will be appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

This is my NSAttributedString extension:

```
 extension NSAttributedString {

  func attributedStringWithResizedImages(with maxWidth: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    
    let text = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
    text.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.attachment, in: NSMakeRange(0, text.length), options: .init(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) in
           if let attachment = value as? NSTextAttachment {
               
               let image = attachment.image(forBounds: attachment.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location)!
             
               if image.size.width > maxWidth {

                   let newImage =  image.resizeImage(scale: maxWidth/image.size.width)
                   let newAttribut = NSTextAttachment()
                   newAttribut.image = newImage
                   text.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.attachment, value: newAttribut, range: range)
                 
               }
        
           }
       })
       return text
   }

 }
```

This is the image resizing extension:

```
 extension UIImage {
 func resizeImage(scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let newSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width*scale, height: self.size.height*scale)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!
  }
 }
```

I am using it here:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    let attributedText = self.getAttributedTextFromUserDefault(key: myNotes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedText.attributedStringWithResizedImages(with: textView.bounds.size.width - 20)
 }
```

Those are the functions to save and get the images on first place:

```
   func saveAttributedTextToUserDefault(attributedText: NSAttributedString, key: String) {
    
    do {
        let data = try attributedText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd])

        userDefault.set(data, forKeyPath: myNotes)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getAttributedTextFromUserDefault(key: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    
    if let dataValue = userDefault.data(forKey: myNotes) as? Data {
        do {
            let attributeText = try NSAttributedString(data: dataValue, documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributeText
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }

    }

    return NSAttributedString()
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but don't use `setValue(_, forKeypPath:)` and/or `value(forKey:)`. You should use `set(_, forKey:)` and `data(forKey:)`

Comment: @Willeke I have looked that answer. I tried textView.layoutManager?.defaultAttachmentScaling = NSImageScaling.scaleProportionallyDown but it says: Cannot find NSImageScaling in scope.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem, but looks OK on my project here. Please take a look https://github.com/kasimok/73940285

Comment: @kakaiikaka thanks for your respond. Still not working properly. You can see the entire swift file here: https://github.com/barHopperSF/images I uploaded images from before and after as well to see the problem. I am choosing a photo from picker from my library and text to save. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out the rotation before I save the image

```
func rotateImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    if image.imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.up {
        return image /// already upright, no need for changes
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return copy
  }
```

use

```
let originalImage = pickImage
attachment.image! = rotateImage(image: originalImage!)!
```